# argument provided to the thread function prints garbage in pthread

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to print value of argument which is provided to the thread function "monitor_loglevel_change_handler" as a last param in pthread_create()
but it prints garbage instead of proper value. However, that is provided and printed properly earlier in the code see the comments

****(Updated my code further with minimum reproducible example as asked by others. Note I have put sleep intentionally in the main program so that thread function gets chance to run)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/inotify.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

char *read_env_param(const char*envkey)
{
    if(envkey)
    {
        char *value = getenv(envkey);
        if(value)
            return strdup(value);
    }
    return NULL;
}



static void * monitor_loglevel_change_handler(void* arg)
{
    char *fileName = (char*) arg;
    int ifd;                   // the inotify file des
    int wfd;                   // the watched file des
    ssize_t n = 0;
    
    char* dname=NULL;          // directory name
    char* bname = NULL;        // basename
    char* tok=NULL;
    
    printf("Value of arguments:  %s\n", (char*) arg);   // --------> prints nothing why??

    dname = strdup( fileName); // defrock the file name into dir and basename
    if( (tok = strrchr( dname, '/' )) != NULL ) {
        *tok = '\0';
        bname = strdup( tok+1 );
    }

    ifd = inotify_init1( 0 ); // initialise watcher setting blocking read (no option)
    if( ifd < 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "### ERR ### unable to initialise file watch %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
    } else {          
        wfd = inotify_add_watch( ifd, dname, IN_MOVED_TO | IN_CLOSE_WRITE ); // we only care about close write changes
    }
}
  
static int register_log_change_notify(const char *fileName)
{
    pthread_attr_t cb_attr;
    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_attr_init(&cb_attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&cb_attr,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    printf("file name is  %s\n", fileName);
    return pthread_create(&tid, &cb_attr,&monitor_loglevel_change_handler,(void *)fileName);
}

int enable_log_change_notify(const char* fileName)
{
    int ret = -1;
    struct stat fileInfo;
    printf("filename is  %s\n", fileName);    // ----> prints properly
    if ( lstat(fileName,&fileInfo) == 0 )
    {
        ret = register_log_change_notify(fileName);
    }
    return ret;
}

void dynamic_log_level_change()
{
    char *logFile_Name = read_env_param("TESTSHA");
    char* log_level_init=NULL;
    if(logFile_Name)
    {
        printf("logFile_Name is :%s\n", logFile_Name);
        free(log_level_init);

    }
    enable_log_change_notify(logFile_Name);
    free(logFile_Name);

}

void init_log() {
    int log_change_monitor = 0;
    dynamic_log_level_change();
}


int main()
{
  init_log();
  sleep(50);
}
```

full code of above is here  [sctpThread.cpp](https://github.com/o-ran-sc/ric-plt-e2/blob/master/RIC-E2-TERMINATION/sctpThread.cpp)

Comment: Where does the memory for that pointer `lifetime` come from? Is it defined to have a longer lifetime than just during the call of that callback? The thread function will be executed later. Probably after you have returned from that callback. You may need to allocate your own memory and provide it to your thread function.

Comment: Perhaps the pointer `fileName` and `arg` no longer points to valid data when you need that pointer? We really need a proper [mre] to be able to actually help you, and not guess.

Comment: sorry, new to C language. Can i get a one or two line just as an example?

Comment: If you're new to C (or C++) you should not be messing with multithreading but start with the basics - both languages are extremely unsuited to the modern "guess and google" attempts at learning. Also, C and C++ are very different languages. Don't tag both unless you're asking specifically about their differences.

Comment: you are write @molbdnilo but i have to fix something spontaneously for which i can not learn the whole Langauge from scratch and be master of it . Anyway i am try to post with minimal reproducible example as said by others

Comment: So you are writing in C, then? C++ is a different language.  Please edit the tags to indicate only the one of those two that you are actually using.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you show.  The problem is in the code you don’t show.

Comment: Aside: Is the `monitor_loglevel_change_handler` thread supposed to keep running? At the moment it just registers something with inotify and then terminates itself by falling off the end of its start routine without a proper return value. You don't need a thread to do that.

Comment: I have added a link of full code of above in the main discussion board above. It is a single file hence will not be a problem to refer. i hope.

Comment: @IanAbbott yes monitor_loglevel_change_handler  should keep on running to check any file change which contains the log level config info

Comment: along with full code link, i have also updated further with  minimal reproducible example

Comment: You could `strdup` the filename in `register_log_change_notify` and use the duplicated string as the thread argument. Then let the thread free the memory for the duplicated string when it has finished using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> free(logFile_Name);
> ```

You are freeing the memory, it is no longer valid.

---

The simple solution is to transfer ownership for the memory to the thread.

```
return pthread_create(&tid, &cb_attr,&monitor_loglevel_change_handler,
     // allocate new memory dynamically 
     strdup(fileName));
```

And then the thread is responsible for free-ing:

```
static void * monitor_loglevel_change_handler(void* arg) {
    .... blabla .......
    free(arg);
}
```

Comment: +1. The fact that you put a sleep doesn't ensure the thread would run before the free by the main thread. I'd say swap the sleep with a semaphore-take, or do as stated by this answer.

Comment: what is semaphore-take?